# Never ending typescript compilation with gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp

I'm trying to compile my typescript files with gulp and gulp-typescript npm modules. I've already done that with many apps before, but never ran into that issue that I don't seem to be able to resolve by my own. The 'compile' task starts, but never ends. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return del('./public/dist/**/*');
});
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function(){
    return gulp
        .src('./public/ts/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist'))
});
gulp.task('connect', function (cb) {
    exec('node server', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    });
})
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(['./public/ts/**/*.ts'], ['compile', 'connect'])
        .on('change', function(event){
            console.log('\x1b[33m', 'The file ' + event.path + 'has been modified.');
    });
});
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'compile', 'connect']);
```

And here is my tsConfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
      "exclude": [
          "node_modules",
          "typings/main",
          "typings/main.d.ts"
      ]
}
```

My architecture looks like:

```
\myapp
    \--public
        \--ts
        \--dist
        index.html
    gulpfile.js
    tsconfig.json
```

Everything but my 'compile' task seems to be working fine. Please, any idea why something's going wrong? I've been searching for hours, looking for differences with other working projects, but didn't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The issue came from my `tsconfig.json` file. The line `"outDir": "dist"` seemed to be overwriting my `.pipe(gulp.dest('myapp/dist'))` in `gulpfile.js`. Silly mistake, since I didn't need that line of code, but I copied/pasted it from an ancient project, and didn't think the compilerOptions should vary. Anyway, issue resolved, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> The 'compile' task starts, but never ends

You will have to share your code. You might want to create an issue at the official repo, something like this : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8401

If you do not want to share your code:

- You will be asked to setup a `typescript` build environment
- take stack traces to pin down the file (e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8401#issuecomment-216545807)
- Send just that file as a repro.

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function(){
    return gulp
        .src('myapp/ts/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('myapp/dist'))
});
```

First of all, can you please verify the path in .src? it is passing `myapp/ts/**/*.ts` but in your architecture, the `ts` folder seems to exist with in the `public` folder under `myapp` so it should look like `myapp/public/ts/**/*.ts`

Comment: Yeah, seems like I messed up a bit my architecture syntax. In fact, I renamed folders (which had quite complicated names), for the purpose of the post, and I failed recoding with new names, silly as I am.The line `.src('myapp/ts/**/*.ts')` should be `.src('public/ts/**/*.ts')` as my gulpfile.js and tsconfig.json files are already in the `myapp` folder. I'll edit the main post with the correct path (and the architecture too, so that it's clearer my gulpfile et tsconfig are into the myapp folder). But the thing is, even with a working path, it doesn't compile.